# How to create a shortcut which recall application that has been pressed in stack?

Tags: android, shortcut

I mean when you create a shortcut not like this:

```
Intent target = new Intent();
target.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
target.setComponent(this.getComponentName());
target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, target);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

when you start the application and start an activity not same to the "target intent" in the shortcut. And press home key. The application press in  background. And wen you press the shortcut icon the target activity is not just the one.

very sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I browse the launcher2 source, i find the way to solve the problem.

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                 intent2.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                 intent2.setComponent(componentName);
                 intent2.setFlags(
                 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |         
                 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);




                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
                Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(v.getContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "XXX");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, intent2);
                v.getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```